# How to specify dates in a U.S. résumé?

Tags: american-english, dates

What is the correct (or at least preferred) way of formatting dates in a résumé whenever you don't need to specify a day?

For example, I am using the format *“May 2011”*, but I don’t know whether I should use *“May, 2011”* or *“May ’11”* (although this one doesn’t seem too appropriate for a résumé).

Comment: The word *résumé* has two accent marks, not just one.

Comment: @tchrist - Many dictionaries do include the *resumé* spelling (and I think it was what I learned in school). Check out the [wiktionary talk page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9) if you can stand even more discussion on this point :)

Comment: I have undone tchrist's accent changes since it is a matter of preference.  I note the misspelling 'prefered' has remained despite all the hoopla over the accents.

Comment: There must be a "résumé" mafia or something.  @tchrist rejected my edit to change résumé back to the (just as correct) form used by the OP: resumé.  It's a mite silly for moderators to enforce their own preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely “May 2011” — no comma needed — particularly if you think your resume might be around for 100 years or more ;^)

If you refer to a longer month, you can use, for example, “Nov. 2011”.

(By *longer*, of course, I mean a longer *word*, not a longer *month*.  I realize May is longer than November).

Comment: It is better to not use abbreviations or shortened words wherever possible on a résumé.  Recruiters (I know because I have been one myself) do not like this at all.